# Query about using JOB or NOT

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, background-process

I have a table called Talk that goes like this:

```
create table talk (
 id_talk,
 home_talk,
 fin_talk,
 state)
```

Well what I want is to do a check between the field `fin_talky` and `sysdate` because, if the latter is greater than `fin_talk` then the `state` (that by default is 1) goes to 0. I was looking at the use of JOB but not if it will result. I hope your experience can guide me. Thank you!

The logic is something like it:

```
From Mondays to Sundays
Time -> 12:00:00 am
Perform
   -> Verification
IF sysdate> end_date THEN
   -> Change "status" of 1 -> 0
IF NOT
   -> Do not change "status"
Until the next time ...
```

Comment: A background JOB is intended for tasks like this. Not sure what you're afraid it might result in.

Comment: So, I must create a procedure to encapsulate that logic and after that create the job and run?

Comment: Yes, that's how jobs work.